# How to initialize a keras tensor employed in an API model

Tags: api, initialization, keras, tensor

I am trying to implemente a Memory-augmented neural network, in which the memory and the read/write/usage weight vectors are updated according to a combination of their previous values. These weigths are different from the classic weight matrices between layers that are automatically updated with the fit() function! My problem is the following: how can I correctly initialize these weights as keras tensors and use them in the model? I explain it better with the following simplified example.

My API model is something like:

```
input = Input(shape=(5,6))
controller = LSTM(20, activation='tanh',stateful=False, return_sequences=True)(input)
write_key = Dense(4,activation='tanh')(controller)
read_key = Dense(4,activation='tanh')(controller)
w_w = Add()([w_u, w_r])                            #<---- UPDATE OF WRITE WEIGHTS
to_write = Dot()([w_w, write_key])
M = Add()([M,to_write])
cos_sim = Dot()([M,read_key])
w_r = Lambda(lambda x: softmax(x,axis=1))(cos_sim) #<---- UPDATE OF READ WEIGHTS
w_u = Add()([w_u,w_r,w_w])                         #<---- UPDATE OF USAGE WEIGHTS
retrieved_memory = Dot()([w_r,M])
controller_output = concatenate([controller,retrieved_memory])
final_output = Dense(6,activation='sigmoid')(controller_output)`
```

You can see that, in order to compute w_w^t, I have to have first defined w_r^{t-1} and w_u^{t-1}. So, at the beginning I have to provide a valid initialization for these vectors. What is the best way to do it? The initializations I would like to have are:

```
M = K.variable(numpy.zeros((10,4)))       # MEMORY
w_r = K.variable(numpy.zeros((1,10)))     # READ WEIGHTS
w_u = K.variable(numpy.zeros((1,10)))     # USAGE WEIGHTS`
```

But, analogously to what said in [#2486](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2486)(entron), these commands do not return a keras tensor with all the needed meta-data and so this returns the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'

I also thought to use the old M, w_r and w_u as further inputs at each iteration and analogously get in output the same variables to complete the loop. But this means that I have to use the fit() function to train online the model having just the target as final output (Model 1), and employ the predict() function on the model with all the secondary outputs (Model 2) to get the variables to use at the next iteration. I have also to pass the weigth matrices from Model 1 to Model 2 using get_weights() and set_weights(). As you can see, it becomes a little bit messy and too slow.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

P.S. Please, do not focus too much on the API model above because it is a simplified (almost meaningless) version of the complete one where I skipped several key steps.

Comment: Try `w_w = add([w_u, w_r])`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you want them to be weights that update during training? You must create custom layers. Or they will be just constants.

Comment: Interesting. Yes the idea is that the weights change at each iteration of the learning how to interface with the memory. But I did not think that they stay constant... Anyway, what are you proposing exactly? To replace the Add() layers that I use for the updates with a custom layer that receive as inputs the addends and that can initialize them in case they are not defined? Or maybe custom layers do accept as input the K.variable() objects?